# delphi object lifetime, interface re-assignment (simple question)

Tags: delphi, interface, reference

It is well known (???) that Delphi reference-counts interface references to interfaced objects, and destroys the objects when their reference counts drop to zero, normally because all relevant interface variables fall out of scope.

Suppose I use a global interface variable to refer to a persistent object:

```
type 
  tMySyncClass = class(TInterfacedObject,TmyInterface); ...  
  tMyAsyncClass = class(TInterfacedObject,TmyInterface); ...

var MyInterfaceVar : TmyInterface;

procedure MyProc();
begin
  MyInterfaceVar := tMySyncClass.create();
  ....
  MyInterfaceVar := tMyAsyncClass.create();
end
```

After calling `MyProc`, I have an instance of `tMyAsyncClass`, with one (global) `MyInterface` reference to it.

Do I still have an unreferenced `MySyncClass` object? Does re-assigning `MyInterfaceVar` trigger destruction of the first (`SyncClass`) object?

Comment: To answer your question yourself: why don't you give the tMySyncClass and tMyAsyncClass classes their own destructor?

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau You're the last person I'd argue with about what ideomatic terms should be used for clarity when addressing the Delphi community, but objectively "interface object", is all wrong :). My objects are TInterfacedObjects, not TInterfaceObjects: I can't even do o=TmyInterface.create();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning an interfaced object to an interface variable will increment the refcount of the object being assigned, and decrement the refcount of the object the variable was previously referring to.

So yes, re-assigning the `MyInterfaceVar` variable will remove the reference to the `tMySyncClass` object, decrementing its refcount and thus freeing the object since it has no more active references.